# Django: TemplateDoesNotExist (rest_framework/api.html)

Tags: django, django-views, django-rest-framework

In my view function, I'd like to return a json object (data1) and some text/html (form). Is this possible?

MY code

```
@api_view(['POST'])
@permission_classes((AllowAny,))
def create_user(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        if request.method == 'POST':
            serializer = SignupSerializer(data=request.data)
            print 'ser'
            print serializer
            if not serializer.is_valid():
                return Response(serializer.errors,\
                                status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
            else:
                serializer.save()
                data={'status': 'Created','message': 'Verification email has been sent to your email. Please verify your account.'}
                return Response(data, template_name='register.html')
    else:
        return HttpResponse('hello world')
```

When I call the url I get status code 500 with error as displayed below

> TemplateDoesNotExist rest_framework/api.html

when I check as a API, I get response with 200 ok status. This shows Im unable to get my html page

How should I get my html depending on request?

Answer (score 421):

Make sure you have `rest_framework` in your settings's `INSTALLED_APPS`

Comment: Its already present. I believe @api_view is not allowing me to render html page..Is there any other solution

Comment: You want to double check that by opening the django shell and looking at the INSTALLED_APPS. It's unlikely api_view since I got it working and it would return an HTTP 415 Unsupported Media Type.

Comment: this function works with CURL command, I also get response, when i try to render html with my browser, I get the above listed error

Comment: This should be selected has answer?

Answer (score 89):

Make sure you install `pip install djangorestframework` and include rest_framework in the setting.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'rest_framework',
]
```

Answer (score 33):

*This is my attempt to explain the problem and collect everyone else's responses into a single list. Thanks to everyone for giving me shoulders to stand on!*

I believe this happens because Django REST Framework wants to render a template (`rest_framework/api.html`), but the template can't be found. It seems there are two approaches to fix this:

## Approach 1: Make templates work

Ensure REST Framework is included in [`INSTALLED_APPS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#std:setting-INSTALLED_APPS) in `settings.py`:

```py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'rest_framework',
    ...
]
```

And ensure [`APP_DIRS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#std:setting-TEMPLATES-APP_DIRS) is `True` in your template configuration (it defaults to `False` if not specified). This allows Django to look for templates in installed applications. Here's a minimal configuration that seems to work, though you might have more config here:

```py
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'APP_DIRS': True,
    },
]
```

## Approach 2: Return a JSON response

If you tell REST Framework to render a JSON response then it doesn't need to use a template so you don't need to change the `APP_DIRS` settings as mentioned above. It also seems like you might not even need to list rest_framework in `INSTALLED_APPS`, though it might be necessary to have it there for other reasons.

You can do this globally in settings.py:

```py
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.renderers.JSONRenderer',
    ]
}
```

Or if you're using the `@api_view` decorator then you can specify JSONRenderer on each view:

```py
@api_view(['GET'])
@renderer_classes([JSONRenderer])
def some_view(request):
    return Response({'status': 'yay'})
```

See [the REST Framework renderers documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/renderers/) for details.

Answer (score 28):

I also had same kind of problem.
Make sure you have rest_framework installed in your setting in "installed apps"

Answer (score 15):

'''
Try one of these for sure help you out:

1: add rest_framework to settings.py app list, sometime order in which your applications are listed may be the reason.
'''

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'rest_framework',
    ...
]
```

'''
2: review your template settings. See Backend, DIR and APP_DIRS. in case you have customized the rest-framework template please check if the path you have defined is correct, make APP_DIRS: True . In most of the cases this will resolve.
'''

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [BASE_DIR, os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        ....
    }
]
```

'''
3: check the default renderer classes settings:
'''

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.renderers.JSONRenderer',
        ...
    ]
}
```

'''
4: If you are using api_view decorators on function based view make sure you have provided renderers correctly. i.e.

@renderer_classes([JSONRenderer])
'''

Comment: At last! 24 hrs of intense hunt later, I find this as the solution that worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 14):

Make sure that you added `rest_framework` in your `installed_apps` to your `settings.py` file:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'rest_framework',
]
```

Answer (score 12):

I hit this issue when upgrading from an old Django version to Django 2.0.  My `settings.py` did not have a `TEMPLATE` directive at all, so I snagged the following from a new `django-admin.py startproject ...` run:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Add that to your `settings.py` if you don't have `TEMPLATES` directive in your `settings.py`.  Worked for me.

Comment: Specifically, in my case, 'APP_DIRS': True got overlooked; that fixed my issue.

Answer (score 11):

I have come across the same issue and found out that rest_framework wasn't added to the installed apps in settings.py. Adding it resolved my issue.

Answer (score 6):

`setting.py` add rest_framework , if rest_framework is not added

Ex:

`INSTALLED_APPS = ["rest_framework"]`

Comment: Why is this needed though ?

Answer (score 3):

The order of the installed apps matters a lot. In my case i added 'rest_auth' above 'rest_framework' so it gave this error but when i reordered it ('rest_framework' above 'rest_auth',  'rest_auth.registration', 'rest_framework.authtoken' etc), this error cleared.

sample Proper order below:

INSTALLED_APPS = [

```
...
'rest_framework',
'rest_auth',
'rest_auth.registration',
'rest_framework.authtoken',
...
```

]

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Other than adding `'rest_framework'` inside your `INSTALLED_APPS`, try adding the following inside your `TEMPLATES.OPTIONS`:

```
'loaders': [
     'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
     'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader'
],
```

Answer (score 2):

In installed apps if you used `rest_framework` in your project add `rest_framework` in `setting.py` file:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'rest_framework',]
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding this decorator above that view 
@renderer_classes([JSONRenderer])

Answer (score 1):

instead of using HttpResponse, use:

```
from rest_framework.response import Response

return Response(data=message, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced a same issue. But I installed `django_filters` and did not included it in `INSTALLED_APPS`. After putting it in `INSTALLED_APPS`, it worked. So look for other third party apps as well.

Answer (score -1):

I have came across the same problem, I was sending an empty response. Try to put a different infomation into `Response()` in `create_user` function to check if it works at all